# My program needs **read** and **execute** access to files in "Program Files (x86)" directory

Tags: windows, c++-cli, uac, administrator

Question as title : My C++/cli Windows program needs to open for **read** and **execute** access (but **not** write access) some files in "Program Files (x86)" directory so it can perform a verification step which I don't want to discuss here.

I have set [Properties/Linker/Manifest File/UAC Execution Level] to "highestAvailable (/level='highestAvailable')" but I get access permissions errors for the files I need to read from.  If I set [...UAC Execution Level] to "requireAdministrator (/level='requireAdministrator')" then my program runs fine and can access the files as required but in this case it obviously runs as the administrator and uses the wrong user profile files etc.

How can I set my program to run as the current user but still have **read** access to files in the "Program Files" directory ?  Is this even possible ?

To forestall a few hares from running, I should say that the current user does have "Read & execute" as well as "Read" access to the relevant files.

Thanks,

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that you don't have read and execute access to the files.  The more likely explanation is that a bug in your program is requesting write access.  Identify the particular calls that are failing, and if you can't work out what's wrong with them, post the code.

Comment: @Harry: Yes, you guessed the right answer,  I was relying on an internal library which does open the files for Read/Write access and it was this that was falling over.  I changed the UAC Execution level back to normal after also trying disabling it in the Manifest file (which is a bad idea btw).  Thanks for your assistance.